# How can i find the result of Debugging topology in storm?

Tags: apache-storm, topology

I'm new to storm trying to use deubugging

i forced `topology.debug: true` in `storm.yaml`

but when i finished sumbiting topology couldn't find where is the result of debug

I noticed in `storm ui` that `topology.debug is false` !

why it coudln't read my changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each node/machine in you cluster has it's own `storm.yaml` file. Thus, your changes to your local `storm.yaml` does not have any effect. However, you can overwrite this value via a topology configuration that is provided when you submit the topology:

```java
Config cfg = new Config();
cfg.setDebug(true);
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("myTopology", cfg, builder.createTopology());
```

You will find the log files on the nodes in you cluster in `your_storm_dir/logs/`

Comment: Thanks I'll try it , but what if i set port for drpc 3773 in the code and ran the storm without any changw fie drpc in stoem.yaml and I've another problem can I make another post or ask here ?

Comment: If it is not related, please start a new question. :)

Comment: I edited my comment for related question and I'll post another post after some minutes

Comment: i accepted your answer because storm ui didn't read that topology.debug true so i chaged in the code but until now i didn't see any debug in logs file it's normal as first

Comment: There is no special file for it. The worker/topology log will contain more information if debug mode is enabled.

Comment: please what is the use of debugging here , i recived in log files what happened and when i got error i executed the java command in supervisor for example in terminal then got the cause of error in worker , i mean what is  the difference here

Comment: Enable logging sets logger level to `DEBUG` (or even `TRACE`; not sure). Thus you should see much more information about the overall processing progress in general with the corresponding prefix saying debug (or trace). An exception that gets logged cannot contain more information though. It depends on the problem you want to track down if debug mode is helpful or not. In same cases, debug mode give huge log files and it can be hard to filter the relevant information... What kind of problem du you try to debug? Any other SO questions? If yes, you should ask there to keep clean Q&A threads.

Comment: thanks , you are the only one here asnwer me with useful answers , the problem with me i searched for it before here and in the storm-users and dev  but until now couldn't fix it , it related to another posts i posted and waiting answer from you there hope you can help

Comment: I try to help on all Storm related question. If I don't answer or ask for more details, I have just no idea whatsoever how to solve the problem.